# find words before and after a keyword in PHP

Tags: php, search

What i'm trying to do is search for a word (or couple of words) and then return a string of 5 words before, and 5 words after the keyword.

My PHP code is like this:

```
function getPreview($keyWord, $searchArea) {
    preg_match("/(\w+)? ?(\w+)? ?(\w+)? ?(\w+)? ?(\w+)? ?$keyWord ?(\w+)? ?(\w+)? ?(\w+)? ?(\w+)? ?(\w+)?/i", $searchArea, $result);
    foreach ($result as $res) {
        return preg_replace("/$keyWord/", "<B>$keyWord</B>", $res);
        break;
    }
}
```

The only problem is, when there aren't 5 words before, or after, PHP doesn't return this.

Does anyone know how I can make this more dynamicly? So PHP knows how many words there are..?

Thx!

Comment: oh btw, i've looked for this on stackoverflow, but the couple of words PHP has to return is hardcoded..

Comment: can you give an example of correct return and a case where it doesn't work? just to understand better what you want to achieve.

Comment: Well, actualy, it's like google search, where you can see a piece of the page where your searchquery was found in..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want i guess:

```
$re = '/((\w* ){0,5})(keyWord)(( \w*){0,5})/i'; 
$str = 'klaus steven keyword peter holger und so weiter und so fort'; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

It has "*word followed by space*" for 0 to 5 times, then your keyword and then another "*space followed by word*" for 0 to 5 times.

See it working with more information [here](http://regex101.com/r/gI9pW7)

Comment: Hey, this works, but the problem is, I want 5 words before and after, but when there aren't 5 words before the keyword PHP doesn't show the string with only 2 words for example...

Comment: I made an EDIT specific for 0 to 5 words 3 minutes ago if that's what you mean.

Comment: I See... this works good. But I have still one problem, sometimes, when people search a word, like "werken", it can be found in anonther word like "samenwerken", and this won't work if it searches for words with spaces... :s

Comment: Well, can'T you figure that out for yourself? The regex101 Page gives a lot of information about the regex and how Regular Expressions work. Do a little work yourself. Hint: create a character ground searching for word characters in front of your kexword with a counter of 0 to endless. And after your keyword as well. OT: What the hell is *samenwerken*? :D

Comment: Allright, many thanks for your help! and "samenwerken" is dutch for "work together" :D

Comment: Consider marking my answer as accepted so this question will not attract more unnedded attention. that would be lecker :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with regular expressions, this one can work with less words. Also, you'd want to escape the keywords in case it contains a question mark or any other regex char.

```
$escapedKeyword = preg_quote($keyWord,'/');
preg_match("/(\w+ ){0,5}?$escapedKeyword( \w+){0,5}/", $searchArea, $result);
```

The ? marker after the {0,5} quantifier, makes it ungreedy. Meaning it will try to take as few words as possible before the match, enabling it to work when there are less than 5 words preceding the keyword.

Also you might want to look into preg_match_all and work on the replacement code.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution is using an explode, then make an array_search in the resulted array. This array is numerically indexed so you can simply know how many words are before and after your answer.
Something like this could work (not tested) :

```
<?php
function getPreview($keyWord, $searchArea) {
    $results = explode(' ', $str);
    $indexOfMyKeyword = array_search($keyword, $results);
    $before = array_slice($results, $indexOfMyKeyword, -5);
    $after = array_slice($results, $indexOfMyKeyword, 5);
    return implode(' ', $before).' '.$keyword.' '.implode(' ', $after);
}
```

You can optionnaly check if your keyword is present using in_array before trying to extract his position with array_search.