# data preview based on keyword PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to do a preview, from a database, and want the preview to be say, 20 words before and after the keyword. I can think of a couple of ways to do this, but seems it would work the server very hard.

One way is to break the data into a word array, with `str_word_count()`, then search the array, for the word index, and do the math, but it just seems like it would be hitting the server too hard.

Is there a better way of doing this?

"20" is just an example, and would trap for a length less than 20, so I know about trapping bad values. However, I do see other issues that may arise, such as, the keyword appears more than once, or if more than one search word is used, so I know it is not as easy as grab an array and do the math.

EDIT: It looks like the mod added link will do the trick. Will test now. Also for those that asked about the output:

Data: "this would be from the database, and got selected using full text query, the keyword used is 'selected'"

Output wanted: "database, and got SELECTED using full text".

Comment: Please can you provide an example of the output you'd like? Also, it's your application, so you're the only one who can tell us what needs to happen if a given keyword exists multiple times in the string...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find words before and after a keyword in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468973/find-words-before-and-after-a-keyword-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon the biggest drawback is querying those results, regardless of any string operations performed later on, either way it`s gonna cost you performance.

I'd go with javascript on this one, return the data from the PHP and have javascript find the words you`re looking for. It saves on your server's load by letting the browser figure it out.

But if you're dead set on using PHP, i`d go with what you've suggested, transform the string in an array of words and return the words based on the offset given.

in jQuery and javascript it could like like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "path/to/script.php",
    complete: response( response ){

        // assuming we`re getting a json result
        // in the following format:  
        // { 
        //      "sentence": "This is my sentence with a word that should highlight the first and last 20 words..", 
        //      "word": "hightlight"
        //  }

        var offset = 20;
        var output = createHightlight(response.sentence, response.word, offset);
    }
});

function createHighlight(sentence, word, offset ){

    var string = "";
    var words = sentence.split(" ");
    var index = words.indexOf(word);

    offset = offset !== undefined ? offset : 20;

    var start = 0, end = words.length;

    if( index - offset >= 0){
        start = index - offset;
    }

    if( index + offset < words.length){
        end = index + offset;
    }

    for( var i = start; i <= end; i++ ){
        string += words[i] + " ";
    }

    return string;
}
```

Comment: Recommending another language that was never mentioned in the OP's question is bad form, especially without providing a minimal example.

Comment: I think it's a good suggestion, considering OP is asking for better alternatives (pretty open-ended). However, I do agree that a working example should be provided.

Comment: Javascript or jquery is fine.

Comment: Thanks Merv, that works too, not sure why you got a "-1", i tried to up vote, but i am still a n00b here and do not have that power =).

Comment: Haha no problem, hope it helps you out though!

Comment: Accepted Merv's Answer. I tried the link the mod posted, but could not get it to work, correctly. It is a nice template, to rework into my code. Although I need to work through a few more "what if's". But, I have a jump-off point.